# magento contact form unable to submit your request

Tags: php, forms, magento, contacts

I am currently in the process of doing a project in magento.
I have a problem with my contact form: emails are not sent to me.
I did a test and I still get this message:

> Unable to submit your request . Please, try again later

Comment: Do you have email server installed?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because an exception is thrown as you can see in the file
`app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` in the `postAction()` function, you should try to debug from here.

Maybe the contact email failled to be sent (if you are in localhost and have no mail server?), that could cause the exception that shows this error.

Comment: thank you for response #adrien54. so I need to install an email server?
because I am in local and I also have a site that is online, but it doesn't work for both

Comment: i need to install mail server?

Comment: this is a possibility but according to your first comment I think the problem may be something else. Look at the function I speak about, try to remove the Zend_Validate::is tests one by one to see if one of them triggers your error.

Comment: i do that but i have the same matter , i think its in my php.ini configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a day as nobody gives a clear answer on the topic.

In order to get it working there are 2 options:

1. Configure smtp server for email sending using smtp pro extension from Magento connect
2. Make Magento use the SendMail function of the webserver

As the first option didn't work for me, as my hosting provider somehow block the smtp outgoing connection, I needed to use the SendMail function.

The quick and dirty trick I used, was to change /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php line 116:

```
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);  → //Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

After this my error message at the contact form was gone and I received
the email correctly.

Be carefull: This is not a good solution as it will be undone at a Magento update. Also it was not tested for the other email functions of Magento.